# UPDATE using html form (edit button) php/mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to figure out how to UPDATE a post in my db using html form. I have a page with a form using INSERT that successfully uploads data to my db. I also have another page presenting that data using SELECT. On this page I would like to have an Edit button, sending me to a similar page with the original form but this with the data from the db already inserted into the form, for easy editing and updating. Basically I don't know where to start and I need your help! It's an album database btw.

**form page**

```
<form method="post" action="spara2.php" name="std">

    <label>Cover:</label><br>
    <input id="file" type="file" name="file"><br>

    <label>Title:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="std_title" size="58"/><br>
    <label>Artist:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="std_artist" size="58"/><br>
    <label for="select"><br>
    Year:</label><br>
    <select name="std_year">

<option value="2014">2014</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2011">2011</option>
<option value="2010">2010</option>
<option value="2009">2009</option>
<option value="2008">2008</option>
<option value="2007">2007</option>
<option value="2006">2006</option>
</select><br>

    <label>Description:</label><br>
    <textarea name="std_beskriv" cols="45" rows="7">
    </textarea><br>
    <label>Tracks:</label><br>
    <textarea name="std_lista" cols="45" rows="7">
    </textarea><br>
    <label>Spotify HTTP Link:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="std_spotify" size="58"/><br>
    <br>
<label for="reset"></label><input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
<label for="save"></label><input type="submit" name="std_save" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

My db is called album and the table musik. I want a similar page but with the data from the db inserted into it. My table has:

1. id
2. title
3. artist
4. year
5. beskriv
6. tracks
7. spotify
8. date

Since there's a lot of posts in the db how can I select specific entry's so that I can edit one album at a time?

Hope you can understand what i'm after.

Thanks!

Comment: for the update logic are you passing the id of the row in the album table to your update logic? I think it would be helpful if you also post your backend insert/update code rather than just the front-end form code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use $_GET to get a specific album from the DB, and use the attributes as default values in the form. Here's an example.

```
Album1 Edit
Album2 Edit
Album3 Edit
Album4 Edit
Album5 Edit
Album6 Edit
```

When you retrieve all the albums from db, you should use the unique id of each album to create a unique path to update a specific album. So the Edit button should have a link of this form: 

`<a href="edit.php?albumID=<?php echo $album[id];?>">`
So after writing this, you will have for the first album edit link: edit.php?albumID=1

To create the edit.php page, first you should fetch from the DB the album by specifiying the ID passed by the $_GET['edit'] parameter in the url. So this will look like:

```
$albumid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['edit']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM musik where albumid = $albumid";
```

If the record was not found, redirect to a 404 page. Otherwise, echo the attributes in the corresponding inputs. 
Ex:

```
<input type="text" name="std_artist" value="<?php echo $album['std_artist'];?>" size="58"/>
```